# Ways to lower app file size using Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, asset-catalog

I'm using `Asset Catalog` to manage all of my app's asset.
I would like to lower the size of the app file.
I did some research and discovered the `Asset Catalog` has support for vector files but that wouldn't help since png files are generated.
What ways do I have to keep the app file size as low as possible using `Asset Catalog`?

Answer (score 0):

Losslessly optimise your PNG images using a tool like: https://imageoptim.com/mac. It works great and could reduce the size of your images by a lot.